# Is a variable declared inside a loop limited in scope by a single iteration?

Tags: java, performance, loops, scope, declaration

I know this sounds trivial but i just want to clear my head about it ..

consider

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int x=i;
    System.println(i);
}
```

is a new int created and allocated memory for each iteration or does the compiler smartly deduce the scenario and create it just once and change its value(since it knows this is a loop),

and as far as the declaration of `i` inside the method signature is concerned,it is obviously created just once right?

also  will

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    x = i;
    System.println(i);
}
```

really be more efficient than the one above?

in java in cases where i will not need to access `x` outside the loop is it better to declare it inside ,which is a good practice?

Comment: Ultimately this won't matter. The JIT will be there for you, so the two versions will eventually turn out to be equivalent. As to what is a good practice, I prefer your second way of doing things while many other people prefer the first... Therefore it's a matter of personal preferences/tastes/coding constraints. In that order.

Comment: Stop worry about "optimizations" like this one. Your bottleneck is in another castle.

Comment: The second one will be more efficient then former one. Because in former it will declare a new int variable on every iteration.

Comment: @Dipen_a when the JIT kicks in it won't matter anymore

Comment: I know it wont matter but can you clarify my doubts a bit

Comment: http://livingtao.blogspot.com/2007/05/myth-defining-loop-variables-inside.html

Comment: Well, don't doubt and just do what you feel the most comfortable with; that is how you keep confidence in your code, right? Also, if you declare it IN the loop, you won't be able to access it OUTSIDE of it. It therefore depends on whether you actually need to access it outside the loop. And yes, the JIT can also detect that.

Comment: @fge: oh... thanks for correcting me. I just google about it.

Comment: Thanks! that added some clarity but just one more thing, each iteration loses the the value for the previous value right?

Comment: As Mr. Anderson (Matrix) would say: "Never send a human to do a machine's job". The Java JIT will most certainly take care of this case and will place the variable in a register.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the bytecode created in both cases.

Declaring the variable outside the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x = i;
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: iconst_0
   1: istore_2
   2: iload_2
   3: bipush        100
   5: if_icmpge     16
   8: iload_2
   9: istore_1
  10: iinc          2, 1
  13: goto          2
  16: return
```

While declaring the variable inside the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int x = i;
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: iconst_0
   1: istore_1
   2: iload_1
   3: bipush        100
   5: if_icmpge     16
   8: iload_1
   9: istore_2
  10: iinc          1, 1
  13: goto          2
  16: return
```

As you can see, the bytecodes are almost exactly the same. The only difference is that, in the first case, `x` is variable 1 and `i` is variable 2 and in the second case `x` is 2 and `i` is 1. So, regarding performance, both codes are equivalent.

Now, regarding design, it's good practice to restrict the scope of your variables when you can. So declaring `x` inside the loop would probably be preferable.

Comment: "regarding design, it's good practice to always restrict the scope of your variables as much as possible" <-- disagree. If you reuse a variable in each iteration of a loop, I, for one, would much rather declare it outside of it. As I mentioned n the comments, this is a matter of preferences. There is no "good practice" to speak of here, only a matter of comfort/preferences/coding styles.

Comment: If you reuse the same value every iteration, I agree with you. Perhaps my assertion was a bit strong here. But it can't be denied that limiting the scope of variables is a well established practice. It's recommended in many books, such as Code Complete and Effective Java, which has a section devoted to it (Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables).

Comment: Yes, I also have Effective Java in my bookshelf ;) (not Code Complete though). And indeed, this is in the scope where you reuse the variable in each and every iteration of the loop. _Personally_, in this case I find it clearer to declare them out of the loop rather than in the loop. Maybe my old C habits get in the way here, I don't know...